# Substring a multiline with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have one text column that have this type of value

```
---
cart_id: 23332251
id: 1824
push: 
key: 
last_checked_in_at: 2019-03-04 10:39:53.946659000 Z
other_field: hello
```

I want to have a column with only `last_checked_in_at` and extract the value as `2019-03-04 10:39:53.946659000`

I tried

```
SELECT substring(object FROM '.*last_checked_in_at: (.*) Z') AS last_checkin_at, *
FROM versions;
```

But I get the begging of the field but it never stop and take the rest of the lines below.

I tried `substring(object FROM '.*last_checked_in_at: (.*) Z$')` but I get NULL. I am on PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: I succeed by having a dedicated regex `substring(object FROM '(\d*-\d*-\d* \d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*)')` but I would to understand why it is not working with the one bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    object text
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
($$---
cart_id: 23332251
id: 1824
push: 
key: 
last_checked_in_at: 2019-03-04 10:39:53.946659000 Z
other_field: hello$$);
```

the SQL

```
SELECT substring(object FROM '.*last_checked_in_at: (.*) Z') AS last_checkin_at, * FROM test;
```

yields

```
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|        last_checkin_at        |                       object                        |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-03-04 10:39:53.946659000 | ---                                                +|
|                               | cart_id: 23332251                                  +|
|                               | id: 1824                                           +|
|                               | push:                                              +|
|                               | key:                                               +|
|                               | last_checked_in_at: 2019-03-04 10:39:53.946659000 Z+|
|                               | other_field: hello                                  |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

So `substring(object FROM '.*last_checked_in_at: (.*) Z')` works as desired.
If you don't want the second column, use

```
SELECT substring(object FROM '.*last_checked_in_at: (.*) Z') AS last_checkin_at FROM test;
```

Comment: But it is the case?

Comment: My mistake. I tested `.*last_checked_in_at: (.*) Z` and I think it should work as desired. I've edited the post above accordingly.

Comment: If this is not the behavior you are seeing with your actual data, then please post `SELECT object::bytea FROM versions LIMIT 3`. Given the values as bytes we might be able to reproduce the behavior you are seeing. We would be able to see if there is a non-visible character that is not accounted for in the regex, for example.